# First non null value from a table with DAX (PowerBI)

Tags: null, powerbi, dax, lookup

I need to find, in DAX, the first value which is not *null* on a related table.

I have a table with multiple (unique) IDs. On another table, I have the same IDs but they are not distinct values, as they are calculated monthly.

These are examples of the tables:

**TABLE 1**

```
ID
    
100010
    
983777 
    
129274 
    
20032
 
6432
```

**TABLE 2**

```
ID  Column2

100010      null

100010      null

100010      null

100010      C2

100010      null

100010      null

100010      C2

100010      null

983777      null

983777      C2

983777      null

983777      null

983777      null

983777      C2

983777      null

983777      null

983777       null

983777       null

983777       null

129274       null

129274       C2

129274       C2

129274       null

129274       null

20032        C2

20032        C2

20032        C2

20032        C2

20032        C2

6432         null

6432         null

6432         null

6432         null
```

The output would be:

```
ID
    
100010  C2
    
983777  C2 
    
129274  C2
    
20032   C2

6432    null
```

I tried with FIRSTNONBLANK, but I checked in Excel and for some IDs it does not return the value "C2":

```
Colonna_C2 = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('TABLE 2'[Column2],1),FILTER ('TABLE 2','TABLE2'[Column2]="C2;" && 'TABLE 2'[ID]=TABLE1[ID]))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate this as (set Show items with no data on ID):

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE ( 
        FIRSTNONBLANK (
            xTab2[Column],
            1  )
    )
```

[image]